# when emit a synchronous I/O call, what`s the ThreadState of the current thread (C#)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

following are my codes:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread current_thread = Thread.CurrentThread;

    new Thread(() => { var i = 0; while (++i > 0) { Thread.Sleep(100); Console.WriteLine("Thread: " + current_thread.ManagedThreadId + ", State: " + current_thread.ThreadState + ", I: " + i); } }).Start();

    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ", State: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState);

        // creating a http request...
        // ...
        requst.GetResponseStream(); // this is the synchronous call 
    }
}
```

output shows that state of current thread(main thread) are always be `ThreadState.Running`. so, why, why not the `ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin`?

the `GetResponseStream()` is synchronous. while waiting for remote response, cpu time slice could(and should) relinquish to other thread, right? (correct me if i`m wrong)

thank you very much.

Comment: How can a thread output its own state if it's not running?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, so i use another thread, see my code.

Comment: But you output the current thread state. Which obviously has to be running, otherwise it cannot output anything.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen another thread was responsible for the output. current_thread was reference to the main thread

Comment: `GetResponseStream` does not actually do I/O, it return `Stream`. I/O will be done when you actually would use this object. .NET does not even have `GetResponseStreamAsync` or `BeginGetResponseStream`/`EndGetResponseStream`, as you does not need one.

Comment: @PetSerAl variable `requst` means `WebRequest` which does have a `BeginGetResponseStream`/`EndGetResponseStream`, plz see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `WebRequest` have `BeginGetResponse`/`EndGetResponse`, but not `BeginGetResponseStream`/`EndGetResponseStream`. `GetResponseStream` is part of `WebResponse`, not `WebRequest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, it's `WaitSleepJoin`. Your sample code is obviously incomplete and wrong (you're not starting the new thread, for example), so it's not easy to say why you're not seeing the proper value. Are you always creating a new request for the `GetResponseStream`?

This code shows what you expected:

```
Thread current_thread = Thread.CurrentThread;

new Thread(() => 
{ 
  var i = 0; while (++i > 0) 
  { 
    if ((current_thread.ThreadState & System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin) > 0) 
      Console.WriteLine("Thread: " + current_thread.ManagedThreadId 
       + ", State: " + current_thread.ThreadState + ", I: " + i); 
  } 
}
).Start();

while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId 
      + ", State: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState);

    var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.google.com/");

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            stream.Read(new byte[2048], 0, 2048);
        }
    } 
}
```

The tricky part is that it's not spending a whole lot of time in the `WaitSleepJoin` state.

Comment: @pinopino The whole process is actually quite complicated (as the above results hint at quite clearly). What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: i am trying to use zeromq. when i call `responder.ReceiveFrame()`, current thread just hanged. so i make some experiments to prove my thought :) thank you Luaan

Comment: @pinopino Try using the Concurrency Visualizer - it usually helps a lot when identifying issues like that. Of course, in your case, it's likely it will simply show the thread doing I/O, but that's pretty much exactly what you're asking for.